Hide <br> after hiding an adjacent <div>
I have made 3 divs, one a little bit above the other, each separared by a <br>. However when my function hides one of them, the <br> is still there, therefore each div is misplaced when all the others are hidden.


function hide1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDiv1");
  if (x.style.display==="none") {
    x.style.display="block";
  }
  else {
    x.style.display="none";
  }
}
<div id="myDiv1">div 1</div> <br>
<div id="myDiv2">div 2</div> <br>
<div id="myDiv3">div 3</div>
<button onclick="hide1()">Toggle div 1</button>



I have 2 more functions for the other divs.
I tried putting the <br> inside the <div> in hopes of <br> visibility being none as well, but it just didn't read it.

I would use classes instead of ids; and give the <br> tags the same class as the corresponding div. Then select all items by the className and iterate over those to show or hide them.

Put the <br> inside the <div> instead of between them.

@Barmar he is already tried that, see the last line of his post...

It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/L1mpe3xf/1/ Please add a [mre].

change <div id="myDiv1">div 1 </div><br> to <div id="myDiv1">div 1 <br><br></div> (with 2 <br> inside)

@Barmar no, your jsfiddle doesn't restpect a new line <br> between the divs

Would setting a margin bottom on the div remove the need for a  spacer?

Lose the br and use CSS margin-bottom.

Agreeing with Scott Marcus — <br> is for breaking a line at a specific place, not for spacing; don't use br to create space between divs, use margins and/or padding as appropriate. As Scott said, you probably want margin-bottom

Forget br in the first place. Breaks should not be used for styling of the layout, they are semantically for adding a line break to content, not page layout.
Instead use CSS classes and create a simple class that can be toggled on or off for the hiding/showing.


// Set up event handlers in JavaScript, not with HTML
document.querySelector("section > button").addEventListener("click", showHide);

const d1 = document.querySelector("#d1");

function showHide(event) {
 d1.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
/* Give all the div elements within a section element a bottom margin */
section > div {margin-bottom:1em;}


/* This class will be toggled on or off to show or hide */
.hidden { display:none; }
<section>
  <div id="d1">div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <div>div 3</div>
  <button>Toggle div 1</button>
</section>



Now to have buttons for each div, there are several approaches, but this approach is highly scalable and only requires one event handler no matter how many div or button elements you may have.
It uses "event delegation", collections of elements and their index positions within those collections, along with the Array.prototype.forEach() method to be able to easily loop over the collection


// First, set up a node-list (collection) of all the buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("section > button");

// Now, set up a node-list (collection) of all the div's
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("section > div");

// Set up a single event handler on a common ancestor of all the buttons
document.querySelector("section").addEventListener("click", showHide);

// This function will now be called whenever any click happens within the <section>
// A reference to the event object that triggered this function is automatically
// passed to the function and we are receiving that reference and calling it "event"
function showHide(event) {
  // The event.target will reference the specific object that triggered the event.
  // In this case, we only care about clicks to the buttons, so first we'll check
  // to see if it was a button that triggered the event
  if(event.target.nodeName === "BUTTON"){
    // Ok, so it was a button that was clicked. 
    // Let's loop through the buttons collection to see which one is the event.target
    // and get its index position within its collection.
    let index = null;
    // .forEach() is the modern way to loop over an array or node list (collection)
    buttons.forEach(function(btn, idx){
      if(btn === event.target) {
        index = idx;
      }
    });
    
    // Now, we'll just toggle the visibility of the DIV that has the same index
    // in its DIV collection (above) as the index of the clicked button from its 
    // BUTTON collection (above).
    divs[index].classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
}
/* Give all the div elements within a section element a bottom margin */
section > div {margin-bottom:1em;}


/* This class will be toggled on or off to show or hide */
.hidden { display:none; }
<section>
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <div>div 3</div>
  <button>Toggle div 1</button>
  <button>Toggle div 2</button>
  <button>Toggle div 3</button>  
</section>




Hey scott this is pretty helpful, however can u explain how i can further add the buttons to hide div 2 and 3? Sorry this is just kinda advanced to me, i tried copying the code again and changing the id but it didnt work..

@Black_Angel Sure. See my second code example with comments. This solution will work no matter how many div and button elements you have in your HTML and does not rely on ids at all.

Instead of using <br> tags to make gaps between divs, use CSS.


function hide(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  x.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
div:not(.hidden) ~ div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
<button onclick="hide('myDiv1')">Toggle div 1</button>
<button onclick="hide('myDiv2')">Toggle div 2</button>
<button onclick="hide('myDiv3')">Toggle div 3</button>
<div id="myDiv1">div 1</div>
<div id="myDiv2">div 2</div>
<div id="myDiv3">div 3</div>




This is a good answer, but it could be improved by adding an explanation of why <br> elements shouldn't be used for layout/spacing.

This actually isn't a great answer as it relies on ! (which you should always strive to avoid) and the CSS selector for the margin is overly complex. See my answer.

It works fine without the !

Just because code "works" does not mean it is correct or even good.

@ScottMarcus It avoids the bottom margin on the last div, to match OP's case.

@ScottMarcus And !important is necessary, if some other CSS rule applies display on the div.

!important is rarely necessary and can usually be avoided by writing better selectors. It essentially breaks the "Cascade" in CSS. Much like goto statements should be avoided in code, !important should be avoided in CSS.

@ScottMarcus I think gre_gor understands that principle, but is trying to make this example more applicable/resilient to be used in the wild where there may already be a display set on the element. Whereas your example won't work if there's already a display property being added with higher specificity by other CSS.

@Sean And my point is that the way to make a style more resilient is to write a better, more specific selector rather than use !important. This is widely understood and in a forum such as this, when helping someone who is new to much of this, we certainly should not be advocating for such techniques.

@ScottMarcus How do I make .hidden more specific, without making it overly complex, without !import.

@gre_gor There are a variety of ways, but I'd start by setting up the HTML structure of the elements that need to possibly be hidden so that they are all within a common parent/wrapper element and apply a class to that element as well as the elements that might get hidden. Then, you could write a selector like wrapperElement.someClass > div.someClass.hidden { display:none; }. This is the essence of CSS. The "Cascade" in CSS is based on selector specificity and how to leverage that specificity, not bypass it.

@gre_gor The other thing to remember is to start with the simplest selectors you can that get the job done and only make them more specific on an as needed basis. By doing this you make the selector easy to override (which is what you want and how "cascading" is implemented in CSS). If you start with extremely specific selectors, you put yourself in a position where overriding becomes very difficult and that's where folks start using !important all over the place, which breaks cascading.

!important rules were meant to give the end user power to override the page-author's styles. The W3C "CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 4" says in §6.3 "This CSS feature improves accessibility of documents by giving users with special requirements [...] control over presentation." Authors should avoid !important in most situations, but see When Using !important is The Right Choice. That also mentions the "reason important rules exist is user stylesheets".

As gre_gor noted, it's better to use css to space your divs (margin-bottom).
It is generally not a good idea to use inline event handlers.
If you actually need the breaks, here is a a way to do that, using event delegation to handle the button.


document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function hide(id) {
  id = `#${id}`;
  const elem = document.querySelector(id);
    if (elem.style.display === `none`){
      elem.style.display = `block`;
      // re-add br
      elem.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterend`, `<br>`);
      return;
    }
    
    elem.style.display = `none`;
    // remove br
    document.querySelector(`${id} + br`).remove();
}

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset?.hide) {
    return hide(evt.target.dataset.hide);
  }
}
<div id="myDiv1">div 1</div> <br>
<div id="myDiv2">div 2</div> <br>
<div id="myDiv3">div 3</div> <br>
<button data-hide="myDiv1">Toggle div 1</button>
<button data-hide="myDiv2">Toggle div 2</button>
<button data-hide="myDiv3">Toggle div 3</button>




Inline event handlers aren't really relevant here and were added by me, for the sake of snippet's simplicity.

Your problem is that you are only hiding the divs, you need to hide the line breaks as well.
    <div id="myDiv1">div 1</div> <br id="br1">

    <div id="myDiv2">div 2</div> <br id="br2">

    <div id="myDiv3">div 3</div>

<script>
function hide1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDiv1");
    var y = document.getElementById("br1");
    if (x.style.display==="none") {
            x.style.display="block";
            y.style.display="inline";
            }
        else {
        x.style.display="none";
        y.style.display="none";
        }

}
function hide2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDiv2");
    var y = document.getElementById("br2");
    if (x.style.display==="none") {
            x.style.display="block";
            y.style.display="inline";
            }
        else {
        x.style.display="none";
        y.style.display="none";
    }

}
function hide3() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDiv3");
   
    if (x.style.display==="none") {
            x.style.display="block";
            }
        else {
        x.style.display="none";
        
    }

}

if you change your code to this, it will look fine.

Most likely because you have two functions that are identical except for what element they work upon instead of setting up a single function that takes an element reference as a parameter. And, also probably because you are using inline styles with if/then instead of CSS classes with .classList.toggle().

I was modifying the code created by black_angel, and that's how they had it set up. If I was creating code from scratch, that's how I would do it.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You're not hiding the <br>.
You're only hiding the <div>.
You should give the <br> elements ids or a class and then hide them with your js script.
for example:
  var x = document.getElementById("br-id");
  if (x.style.display==="none") {
    x.style.display="block";
  }
  else {
    x.style.display="none";
  }


Oh boy. If we're going to get so granular as to give br elements ids so that our page layout works, we're in BIG trouble. And, we don't need if/then with inline styles even if we were to go that route - - simply using a .hidden class and toggling it with .classList.toggle() would be the way to go. But for this issue, just use CSS margin-bottom.

I adapted my example to his code. I offered him to use classes or ids, he can do whatever he likes. If he has only 2 of those  elements, it's reasonable to use ids, especially if you dont know what their role is or what he plans to do with them.

If he doesn't learn how to use classes, he's not free to do whatever he likes. ids are actually very rarely needed in the first place, but to put them on br elements (which shouldn't be used for page layout in the first place) is bad advice.

I'm not saying what you're saying is incorrect, but we don't have the context for what he's trying to do. He may be learning and he's practicing,  maybe this is a small part of a larger code, and he may have his reasons to do this. I don't think assuming things without context is a good idea.

It doesn't matter what he's trying to do, the techniques you've shown are not appropriate for any use case.
